# Spring + Hibernate DAO as generic class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Some time ago I started to learn `java EE`. I swiftly moved to spring(mvc)+hibernate. As I was learning about databases and integration with spring+hibernate I came up with an idea.

As far as I noticed(and understand) there's a common approach to build an objects structure including configuration files, entities, dao interface and dao implementation(as we're talking just about dbs, not controllers and other applications' layers). I decided to write a generic java class and call it `BasicDao`. **It's a template which takes entity as a type.**

This is actually working and I think it's much better than interfaces and implementations, because you need only one class for all entities(if you wanted to write separated implementations for each entity you might end up with a big amount of files).

I also wrote some template functions there so the class is very flexible(no exceptions with types passed to the db). Here's the code

```
package local.bb.dao;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Repository(value = "basicDao")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED,readOnly = true)
public class BasicDao<ENTITY> {

    private Class<ENTITY> data;
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public BasicDao() {
        this.data = null;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addRecord(ENTITY t) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(t);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void removeRecord(ENTITY t) {
        this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(t);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<ENTITY> getAllRecords() {
        return (List<ENTITY>)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(this.data).list();
    }

    @Transactional
    public <TYPE> ENTITY getRecordByParam(String param, TYPE value) {
        return (ENTITY)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(this.data).add(Restrictions.eq(param, value)).uniqueResult();
    }

    @Transactional
    public <TYPE> List<ENTITY> getRecordsByParam(String param, TYPE value) {
        return (List<ENTITY>)this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(this.data).add(Restrictions.like(param, value)).list();
    }

    //  GETTERS / SETTERS

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }


    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public Class<ENTITY> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Class<ENTITY> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


}
```

The question, finally, is: is it a good approach actually? Because I've never seen such code anywhere(speaking about tutorials on the Internet and books).

Comment: Since you are using Spring and Hibernate, the Spring Data JPA project should be a nice read for you. No need to reinvent the wheel, except maybe for learning purposes. But even then Spring Data JPA is a good example of how to do this. http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/

Comment: YAGDI (Yet Another Generic Dao Implementation). There are [several](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-genericdao/) [implementations](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fhibernate-generic-dao%2F&ei=EqM3VYGZDcG2sAHBmoKoAg&usg=AFQjCNEw5wniAJdMLq8bwlIVhOfgneKzRw&sig2=BAufy8avQfXhTslaAHEf2Q&bvm=bv.91071109,d.bGg) all over the internet for the generic dao pattern. Instead of writing your own use an available one, a nice one is Spring Data JPA with which you don't need an implementation at all...

Answer (score 2):

**Spring likes interfaces** since a couple of important mechanism are based on it, e.g. AOP, interceptors. So, if you decide to go without them you have to accept certain limits to Spring functionality. What's more, it will be harder to write Test-Mocks for other classes that depend on your DAOs.

If you want to save code, I suggest you **lose the implementation rather than the interface**. With Spring JPA you can annotate a DAO interface with as set of annotations, i.e. `@Query, @Procedure, @Modifying` etc to define how the data is accessed. If you then enable JPA repositories in your application context, Spring will supply the DAO implementation for you.

More information can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write generic DAO in hibernate and if it's useful and helps you to reduce substantial amount of code and makes your codebase clean then you should go for it. I have used generic DAO but only for simple CRUD operations. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-genericdao/) is a good read on generic persistence layer.